# pandas merge seconds columns into one minute col

Tags: pandas

[image: I have seconds columns like shown in the image i need to merge seconds columns into each minute column please help/advise.]
I have seconds columns like shown in the image i need to merge seconds columns into each minute column please help/advise.

Comment: Please provide your example input [in a reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2023-11-01 10:22:24': ['first'],
                   '2023-11-01 10:22:26': ['second'],
                   '2023-11-01 10:22:28': ['third'],
                   '2023-11-02 10:25:24': ['fourth'],
                   '2023-11-02 10:25:29': ['fifth']})
df = df.T
df.index = df.index.str[:16]
df = df.pivot_table(index=df.index, values=0,
                    aggfunc=lambda x: "".join(str(v) for v in x)).T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   2023-11-01 10:22    2023-11-02 10:25
0  firstsecondthird      fourthfifth
```